# OpenCV for python using VSCode's run stops at 'cv2.VideoCapture(0)' but gives no error

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have a python script that uses the OpenCV library. It works correctly from command line and in the idle editor, but when I use the built in run/Start Debugging option in VSCode with the default launch.json file the program seems to run until `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, but stops on this line?

Using the same launch.json file, other python files (without OpenCV) have run correctly. The code as follows

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print("Test point 1")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print("Test point 2")
```

Outputs the first print statement only

```
>> Test point 1
```

The program then seems to quit as if it has completed successfully with no errors that would normally come up if there was an error (e.g. undefined variable). So the program seems to run correctly until it reaches the `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try-except` block to catch any exception so that the next code runs even if the capture fails.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print("Test point 1")

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print(cap)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print("Test point 2")
```

Comment: I need the video capture in order for the program to work. There is no obvious error message shown. I'm thinking it might be something to do with permission to access the camera on macOS.

Comment: So, you don't get any exception? Then, you just don't have a webcam. Anyway if you don't get any warning / error, it's virtually impossible that your second print statement doesn't run.

Comment: Thats why i'm confused because the same program runs correctly when run in terminal. It must be something to do with VSCode. I don't get any errors/warnings either but the second print statement does not get printed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with VScode and I also think that it's because of the permissions to the webcam for VScode. by the way I don't see VScode in security preferences.

P.S. In my case, when I run the program within VScode, it quits python launcher!